# remove special characters in php

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I have many descriptions with special characters like  é, ô and many more and have tried to remove them with:

```
$string = str_replace("é", " ", $string)
$string = ereg_replace("é", " ", $string)
$string = mysql_real_escape_string($string)
```

But nothing works, the special characters are still there and the description is not inserted in the database. I can't remove all special characters because in the description there are html tags that are needed.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: [_Cannot reproduce_](https://eval.in/127631)

Comment: Is everything UTF8? It sounds like you have a mix of charsets.

Comment: The data base table row that i get them is set to utf8_bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy peasy:**

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

**Usage:**

```
echo clean('a|"bc!@£de^&$f g');
```

Will output: `abcdef-g`

**Edit**:

`Hey, just a quick question, how can I prevent multiple hyphens from being next to each other? and have them replaced with just 1? Thanks in advance!`

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.

   return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); // Replaces multiple hyphens with single one.
}
```

[refer this link](http://www.phpjabbers.com/php-snippet/remove-special-characters.php)

Comment: One moment so i can try it

Comment: It removes all html staring end ending tags symbols, i comment out the  part that remove spaces, because i need them, i need characters like ()<>/

Comment: Tried with `preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-()<>= "\/]/', '', $string)` now the html tags look ok and removes the special characters, tanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

> This function returns a string or an array with the replaced values.

You need to use returned value

```
$string = str_replace("é", " ", $string);
```

Comment: Sorry, i know that, yust forget to write it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [character transliteration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#94946).

Example:

```
<?php
$string = "ʿABBĀSĀBĀD";

echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
// output: ABBASABAD

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($string));
```

Comment: returns a string with length 0

Comment: Do you have a db connection in place??? From the manual: The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.