# How to trim special characters from a sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

trim() is used to clear all the whitespaces. Now, instead of clearing white spaces, I want to eleminate all special characters from the 'username'. Is there any function like trim() for eliminating special characters??
My sql query is like

```
Select value from table_name where trim(username) = 'ABCD'
```

and it returns null value. But there are some values related to 'ABCD' and it displays all the entries when i execute the query

```
select value from table_name where username like '%ABCD%'
```

there are nothing else like visible in 'username' field. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: special characters like ?

Comment: One man's "special" characters are another man's everyday characters...

Comment: question edited. hope you understand the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not have such kind of functionality to remove special characters. Instead you can use replace function (if you know what are special characters).

```
replace("your column name",'_','')
```

Answer (score 1):

**See example :**

```
Select value from table_name where REPLACE(trim(username$),"$","");
```

this if you want to replace the $ with an empty char

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

Call it like this:

```
Select dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters('abc1234def5678ghi90jkl')
```

Once you understand the code, you should see that it is relatively simple to change it to remove other characters, too. You could even make this dynamic enough to pass in your search pattern.

refer this link:***https://stackoverflow.com/a/22684392/3242978***